# connection refused when using dockerfile to pull git repository

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, docker-for-mac, gitea

Local setup for kubernetes: **Mac OS**

```
Docker for desktop >> kubernetes >> traefik >> Gitea
```

The gitea is installed in the cluster and exposed as clusterIP service ingresses through treafik which is accessible at http://gitea.local. Everything is butter smooth till here.

**The pain:**

Now i am creating a dockerfile and using a docker build to build an image. This dockerfile is trying to clone a repository from http://gitea.local. The problem is i am getting connection refused all the times.

```
RUN mkdir -p apps sites/assets/css  \
    && cd apps \
    && git clone http://gitea.local/inviadmin/testing.git
```

Then i simply tried `RUN curl http://gitea.local` from inside dockerfile just to debug and got the same:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to gitea.local port 80: Connection refused
```

if i curl `google.com` from dockerfile its working. Any help is strongly appreciated.

**Dockerfile:**

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.0-experimental

FROM bitnami/python:3.7-prod

ENV NVM_DIR=/root/.nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION=12.18.3
ENV PATH="/root/.nvm/versions/node/v${NODE_VERSION}/bin/:${PATH}"
RUN install_packages wget \
    && wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh \
    && chmod +x install.sh \
    && ./install.sh \
    && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm install ${NODE_VERSION} \
    && nvm use v${NODE_VERSION} && npm install -g yarn

RUN install_packages \
    # when using ssh
    git openssh-client openssh-server iputils-ping
    #git

ARG GIT_BRANCH=master

#RUN ping host.docker.internal

RUN mkdir -p apps sites/assets/css  \
    && cd apps \
    && git clone http://gitea.local/inviadmin/test.git --branch $GIT_BRANCH

FROM nginx:latest
COPY --from=0 /home/test/sample/sites /var/www/html/
COPY --from=0 /var/www/error_pages /var/www/
COPY build/nginx/nginx-default.conf.template /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template
COPY build/entry/docker-entrypoint.sh /

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y rsync && apt-get clean \
    && echo "#!/bin/bash" > /rsync \
    && chmod +x /rsync

VOLUME [ "/assets" ]

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: hey, try nslookup from within the container. Since the domain is .local i think you'll need to add it to the etc/hosts

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ No i m not. If i curl anything all perfect. Only when i curl the url of services running in other container ; getting this error! Furthermore if i visit these from browser , everything is smooth.

Comment: @MuhammadHasan hey i already added gitea.local in private/etc/hosts and that is how i can visit them in browser without any issues.

Comment: Okay. So i did a little experiment. From within the container pinged abc.com. Once it failed I edited the /etc/hosts file using echo "127.0.0.1    abc.com" >> /etc/hosts. After that the ping started hitting the container itself. If you could ping your domain from within the container and it resolves to the correct IP then would could rule this out. But if it fails to resolve to the actual ip then perhaps this could be the actual root cause.

Comment: @MuhammadHasan no luck :(

Comment: okay. so if you try to do a ping from inside the container, whats the error/output?

Comment: @MuhammadHasan Failed to connect to gitea.local port 80: Connection refused

Comment: @prem, can you tell me the /etc/hosts entry on your mac for the gitea.local?

Comment: @MuhammadHasan 127.0.0.1    gitea.local
Also, i have mentioned above, there isnt the problem when i visit gitea.local from the browser. It is only the problem when i access it inside dockerfile to build an image.

Comment: @prem change your run cmd to RUN mkdir -p apps sites/assets/css  \
    && cd apps \
    && echo "<exposed_ip>   gitea.local"  >> /etc/hosts && git clone http://gitea.local/inviadmin/testing.git

Comment: @MuhammadHasan you cant echo to hosts file from dockerfile as it is read only

Comment: @prem, did you atleast tried? I tested it with a sample dockerfile and it took effect for me

Comment: @MuhammadHasan Hey ofcourse i tried. see the error below: #16 0.218 /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /etc/hosts: Read-only file system

Comment: @prem, please post the full Dockerfile so that i can try myself

Comment: @MuhammadHasan i pasted in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tested your dockerfile and here's the outcome [image]

Since the only part you were having issue was the git pull, i chose to use the following lines only.
[image]

Notice from the build that how adding entry to the /etc/hosts took effect for the following commands.
If the issue still persists then i suggest you start looking into the gitea container's logs.

Comment: thanks for the effort. but it is not working in docker mac. Actually the need is pretty simple but yet complicated. i have docker in mac and activated kubernetes plugin which comes with it. I installed gitea and added 127.0.0.1 gitea.local and no problem , i can access it from the browser. pull , push everything is working. Now i started making a docker file pulling some codes from gitea, but during docker build, gitea.local is not at all detected.

Comment: @prem, try using --add-host=google.com:127.0.0.1 in your build command. It worked for me in ubuntu. just replace the dns and ip.