# How to access the service with the same url inside container as it is accessed at the host

Tags: macos, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

Local setup for kubernetes: **Mac OS**

```
Docker for desktop >> kubernetes
```

Let's say i have a service *abc.local* (`127.0.0.1  abc.local`) which i can browse from my host browser. How can i curl this *abc.local* with in a dockerfile during docker build.

Comment: Can you run a host process to generate a file you can `COPY` into your image?  That might be easier.  I don't think there's any way to add vanity names for `127.0.0.1` during the build process, though if `host.docker.internal` works at all (on a Windows or MacOS host) it probably will work in a Dockerfile too.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for the reply. Actually my need is well elaborated here. But since no one replied , i had to post another synonyms. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63341589/connection-refused-when-using-dockerfile-to-pull-git-repository

Comment: This one looks like a legit duplicate of your previous question. The previous question was asked 19h ago, this one 15h ago = after 4h. In other words - _but since no one replied_ sounds a bit weird. SO isn't real-time chat, sometimes it takes even days til someone answers your question, reacts, ...

Comment: Try using `--network=host` while building. You may need to also add `--no-cache`.

Comment: Did you solve it? @prem